# Pass cmd.exe arguments via a shortcut?

Tags: windows, command-line, ruby, right-click, rubygems

I'd like to create a shortcut to run cmd at a particular location with a few commands.

I'm hoping from there I can work out how to make it a right click option to "Run my cmd commands here..."

I've found the shortcuts to run CMD with ruby. Which is part of what I want.
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /E:ON /K C:\Ruby191\bin\setrbvars.bat

Then in the target field I set me location. Now I just need to know how to pass it some startup arguments.

It is basically to help me run livereload easily on folders. LiveReload is a mini webserver/ruby gem that will auto refresh the browser when you save changes to files contained within the folder you're running it in https://github.com/mockko/livereload

So basically it is running cmd, launching ruby, passing in the directory and activating livereload.

Comment: *I'm one of the developers of LiveReload.* I'd like that to. You would also need to somehow show all enabled directories. And an option to stop it.

Comment: I found the fix. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok by following this... http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/registry2/how-can-i-open-a-command-prompt-at-my-current-directory-in-explorer-.aspx?cpage=2

I got as far as this... http://dl.dropbox.com/u/497583/code/livereload.reg
[EDIT] The above file works just fine now. I just need && to seperate commands.

But I need to know how to pass it further commands like "livereload". Also it opens on the folder you're currently in and not the folder you have right clicked.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it and the above file works now!

Answer (score 1):

When you create a batch file (.bat). Any thing that is dragged and dropped will infact turn into a command line parameter.

You can access these parameters with a %1, %2, %3... etc

So in you case `...So basically it is running cmd, launching ruby, passing in the directory and activating livereload...`

in your bat file (assuming your ruby stuff is properly in your path)

```
@echo off
echo %1
ruby myScript.rb %1
EXIT
```

then all you would need to do is drag and drop that directory onto the script and all will run properly

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\livereload] 
@="Livereload" 

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\livereload\Command] 
@="cmd.exe  /E:ON /K C:\\Ruby191\\bin\\setrbvars.bat  & pushd %L & @livereload"
```

works for me... you can edit @="Livereload" to change what it says in the context menu

Comment: Would you mind telling me where did you find the use of %L or explanation page ? i know %L give the whole path, is there another variable, if I just want the current directory name, without the whole path?