# Using DOS commands in a shortcut (.lnk) file

Tags: command-line, shortcuts

Is there a way to create a shortcut (.lnk) file that uses a DOS command line instead of pointing to a file?

It would be great to simply DC a shortcut instead of having to invoke a command line every time I want to do this specific action.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass cmd.exe arguments via a shortcut?](http://superuser.com/questions/256714/pass-cmd-exe-arguments-via-a-shortcut)

Answer (score 3):

Windows shortcuts can point to any command.  If you want to run a "DOS" command, you are probably looking for one of the commands which is part of the `cmd` program (which also can run batch-files).  For running those built-in commands you have to run via `cmd`, e.g.,

```
cmd /k dir
```

but if you want to direct the output of the command to a file, you will have to run that within a batch-file, or in a properly quoted command passed to `cmd`, e.g.,

```
cmd /k "dir >\mydirectory"
```

Keep in mind that the shortcut can be told to run in a particular directory.  If you do not specify it, that will be in the system directory.

Further reading:

- [CMD: Create Shortcut To Command Line/Dos Programs](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/257/cmd-create-shortcut-to-command-linedos-programs/)
- [How to run command prompt commands from desktop shortcuts in Windows](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/06/05/how-to-run-command-prompt-commands-from-desktop-shortcuts-in-windows/)
- [Cmd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490880.aspx)
- [Command-line reference A-Z](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx)
- [shortcut for opening cmd.exe at a certain location](https://superuser.com/questions/374105/shortcut-for-opening-cmd-exe-at-a-certain-location/374111)

Comment: But how do I get that text into a shortcut file? (Also, what is /k?)

Comment: When you create the shortcut, rather than using the name of a file, you can use the name `cmd`.  The `/k` is an option that tells `cmd` to use the next string as its parameter.

Comment: @ThomasDickey To add to that, `/k` runs the next string and *remains open* after completion, whereas `/c` would run the command and terminate the cmd prompt.

Comment: I suggested `/k` since it made the most sense for OP to start there - to see the command results.  As usual, most of the useful information is not really found *here*, but useful answers as a rule point to further sources of information.